# A probability measure that descirbes the Bernoulli Experiment

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I encounter the following probability measure that claim to describe the Bernoulli Experiment

For a fixed element $\omega_0, \omega_1 \in \Omega$ and $\alpha_0, \alpha_1 \in [0,1]$ with $\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 = 1$, $\delta$ as the Driac Measure, define:
$$P:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0,1], \ \ \ P(A) = \alpha_0 \delta_{\omega_0}(A) +  \alpha_1\delta_{\omega_1}(A) \tag1$$
$$\mathcal{A}: \sigma-algebra, A \in \mathcal{A}$$

I am slightly confused by this description particular about what $A$ is. At the moment, I assume that $A$ is implicitly defined non-trivially to be an event (a set) with a single element: either $\omega_0$ or $\omega_1$.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this description is not good, but I don't see any reason why $A$ should be a singleton.  I think $A$ can be any subset of $\Omega$, i.e. $\mathcal A = \{\emptyset, \{\omega_1\}, \{\omega_2\}, \{\omega_1\, \omega_2\}\}$.  In particular, since $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it must contain $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$.

Of course, the events we are likely to care about in this setting are the singleton sets, but we still require the "trivial" events $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ to be in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: My thought about A is that if, let's say, $A=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$, then it just means A is an event that must happen, which is trivial in describing a Bernoulli experiment

Comment: @TJT Yes, it is trivial, but there are technical reasons you want to include it.  It also would be odd to have a framework that can describe (relatively) complicated events, but can't handle trivial ones.